# In Google Colaboratory, is there a way to pay for a larger GPU?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm testing out the GPU support for Colaboratory. The GPUs are of limited RAM.

```
name: "/device:CPU:0" 
device_type: "CPU" 
memory_limit: 268435456 locality { } 
incarnation: 14648174833476954761, 
name: "/device:GPU:0" 
device_type: "GPU" 
memory_limit: 356515840 
locality { bus_id: 1 } 
incarnation: 11566567776783368174 
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, 
name: Tesla K80, 
pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, 
compute capability: 3.7"]
```

The size of the GPU memory is 356MB, I'm wondering if there is a way to get a paid version to increase the GPU memory? Perhaps this is already part of a paid google product, does anyone know what the product is?

Comment: Google Datalab?

Comment: @BenAubin it looks like it. The UI/UX is different, so just wondering if they are designed for different purposes, or if they will get merged together at one point.

From the information, it looks like Collaboratory is strictly playground/educational, and you're asked to switch to Datalab if you want something bigger.

Comment: From my experience, Datalab is better for larger projects, but it starts at $300/month to get a gpu (although it's a full k80)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has introduced a pro version for colab which has access to better GPUs - https://colab.research.google.com/signup

Comment: yeah, i am using it and its insane for deep learning etc. Normally its only for US, but with a credit card you can use it from everywhere, you just need a US zip code for sign up (just google).. its great for 10 bucks per month. You get almost constant access to a telsa p100. It resets every 24 hours, but if you dont have problems with that, its a great deal in my opinion

Answer (score 10):

GPUs in Colab aren't shared. Each user has full access to a k80 with 12G of memory.

Seeing 356MB of free GPU memory almost always indicates that you've created a TensorFlow session without the `allow_growth = True` option. See:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth

If you don't set this option, by default, TensorFlow will reserve nearly all GPU memory when a session is created.

**Good news**: As of this week, Colab now sets this option by default, so you should see much lower growth as you use multiple notebooks on Colab. And, you can also inspect GPU memory usage per notebook by selecting 'Manage session's from the runtime menu.

[image]

Once selected, you'll see a dialog that lists all notebooks and the GPU memory each is consuming. To free memory, you can terminate runtimes from this dialog as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to request a larger GPU with Colab.

Comment: It actually seems to be possible and a supported feature: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Comment: @Herbert You'll be using your own hardware with Colab interface only if you use local runtime.

Comment: @johan True, but *your own hardware* could be rented at AWS for example.

Comment: @Herbert Nice! Didn't thought of that.